# Creating friendly urls to dynamic resources in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, friendly-url

I have a struts2 application with a single page that may show one of a number of values stored in a database. The application is for a school with many departments and each department has many programs. The department page is accessed using a url like this

```
department.action?id=2
```

and the DepartmentAction will load the Department with id = 2 for display. All this is fine if the user is just browsing around the site but it gets uncomfortable if I want to provide a link to say the Engineering department in the newspapers. The link will have to be www.myschooldomain.com/department.action?id=2. I see a number of problems with this.

First, it is not user friendly. Second, it is prone to be broken because the departments are dynamically maintained and the id for a department could change without warning making the link unstable.

I would prefer to print a url like this: www.myschooldomain.com/department/engineering and have that somehow go to department.action?id=2.

My thoughts so far: create an action that will parse the url for the department name at the end then look it up by name. Maybe I could add a friendlyurl field to the database for each department.

But the question is: Is there a better way to do this in struts2?

Thanks.

**Update (May 2009):** I just happened to stumble back over this question and thought that I would say what I did to solve it.

I created a new package in the struts.xml called departments. In this package there is only one action mapped to *. So it catches all requests to mydomain.com/departments/anything.html.

In the action class I simply parse the url and look for the part between departments/ and .html and that is the name of the department so I can do a lookup in the database for it. This has been working fine for almost 5 months now and I have implemented it for other areas of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally done by mapping a servlet to, in your case '/department', and then using the [path](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo()) information (e.g., '/engineering') within the servlet to determine the ID.

Since the Struts2 dispatcher doesn't implement this behavior, it might be simplest to write your own servlet. This servlet would be configured with a map of valid "friendly" names to the unfriendly numeric identifiers. This could be an actual `Map` or it could be done with a database finder method.

The result of `getPathInfo()` would be used to look up the ID, and the request would be [forwarded](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)) to the department.action. Handle the `null` case too, which means the user is trying to browse the `/departments/` directory.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [URL Rewrite filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

This avoids the need for any additional servlet or Java code but requires XML descriptors.

Comment: I didn't mean to resurrect this old thread - I thought I was viewing new answers, doh!